# What does #1 mean in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I understand that `always @(posedge clk)` in verilog is a flip flop.

```
input ld;
reg ld_r;
always @(posedge clk) ld_r <= #1 ld;
```

What does `#1` do in above code? I found it in verilog code for AES. I include a snippet of it below:

```
always @(posedge clk)
if(!rst)    dcnt <= #1 4'h0;
else
if(ld)      dcnt <= #1 4'hb;
else
if(|dcnt)   dcnt <= #1 dcnt - 4'h1;

always @(posedge clk) done <= #1 !(|dcnt[3:1]) & dcnt[0] & !ld;
always @(posedge clk) if(ld) text_in_r <= #1 text_in;
always @(posedge clk) ld_r <= #1 ld;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention that `always @(posedge clk)` infers a flip-flop I assume you are interested in knowing what `#1` is synthesized as in hardware.  The answer is: nothing.

These delays will get ignored in synthesis, so if you use them in design code you run the risk of your simulation not matching your hardware.

Here is a paper that describes why you would want to add delays: http://sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002Boston_NBAwithDelays.pdf

Comment: Ok, I get it. But can you plz explain what could be the purpose of `#1` in the code I just included in my question.

Comment: I am a verilog noob and am just not going to read that paper :P. Well, I will get on with that it does nothing.

Comment: When I have some time I'll try to summarize the relevant parts of the paper.

Comment: @kamalbanga, the `<= #1` is an arbitrary clock-to-q delay. The lhs is updated one simulation time unit after the `posedge clk`.

Answer (score 3):

`#1` Delays by 1 timestep. To find what time step your using you can use:

```
$printtimescale;

> Time scale of (test) is  1ns /  1ns
```

Just using `#1` can be risky because it is based on the last instance of `` `timescale 10ns/1fs ``.

Therefore as files are added or load order changes the definition of `#1` can change. Newer versions of Verilog support the use of units ie `#1ns`. the `1ns` part is a `realtime` and you may perform operations on them as you would any `realtime` variable.

```
//Delay 1001ns
#(1us + 1ns);
```

Intra-assignment

```
ld_r <= #1 ld;
```

Equates to :

```
temp = ld;
#1 ld_r <= temp; // Delay execution of ld_r <= temp by 1 timestep
```

That is take a copy ld **now** and assign its value back to ld_r in `#1`.

The usage of this is explained in [9.4.5 Intra-assignment timing controls of SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012 Standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf):